# Maximum length of stay in Singapore without a visa for Russian citizens?

Tags: visas, singapore, russian-citizens

I'm a Russian citizen living in Australia. I would love to visit Singapore, but I have to travel to another city in Australia to apply for a visa to Singapore. I had read about the 96-hour visa free transit facility (VFTF) for Russian passport holders. How does it work? How long can I stay in Singapore without a visa with my Russian passport?

Comment: 1. VFTF is only valid for *transit*, which means that you have to continue to a 3rd country (other than you arrived from). 2. It is only valid for entry and exit by air only. I have experience of entering Singapore without a visa through land border, but I had to have a short secondary interview, and the officer exercised his discretionary power to admit me. I've also met a few reports of admission refusals at land borders. I've never seen a report that someone was admitted if they were to exit through land border. 3. All you need is your passport and a proof of flight to a 3rd country.

Comment: 4. 96 hours are measured by *scheduled* arrival and departure times. In any case you get a 5-day admission stamp. 5. Singapore has been issuing electronic visas to Russian nationals for a few years now. All you need is $35 (or thereabouts) and there's no need to go to a consulate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you, please, say more about paragraph 5? How can I apply for Singapore visa online?

Comment: Try checking http://forum.awd.ru/viewforum.php?f=1375

Comment: @ach Please add your information as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

While Russian nationals, among others, may be eligible for [Singapore’s Visa Free Transit Facility](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf), you must be travelling to a third country, not the round trip between Australia and Singapore you describe.

> **Nationals of the Commonwealth of Independent States (CIS), Georgia, Turkmenistan and Ukraine**
>
> If you are in transit to or from any third country (both forward and return legs), you may be eligible for the 96-hour VFTF if you have a valid onward air ticket departing within 96 hours. You may enter Singapore by any mode of transport but must depart Singapore by air.

As an Australian resident, you would not have to visit the [High Commission of the Republic of Singapore located in Canberra](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/canberra/visa_information/overview.html) to apply for a Visit Pass.

You can submit your visa application online through [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/singapore/australia/) which has offices located in Sydney, Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide, and Spring Hill.

The visa processing fee is AUD30 and you’ll need the following:

- Completed and signed [Form 14A](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/dam/mfa/images/om/Canberra/Form14A.pdf) with photo attached.
- Original passport (must have at least 6 months’ validity from the intended date of entry).
- Photocopies of confirmed travel itinerary issued (mode of transport can be by plane, train, cruise or car).
- Australian contact numbers and email address, on a separate piece of paper and attached to the application.

Comment: OP can fly on a cheap ticket to a third country through Singapore to avoid applying for a visa.

Comment: I have an India passport and used the VFTF, in December last year, without any issues (I had a valid US visa at the time, and US was my final destination) for a stay of 74 hours, which is plenty of time to see Singapore. My itinerary was BOM to SIN on Air India and SIN to SFO on United. All I had to present was the flight ticket from SIN to SFO at the immigration. The officer was polite but was kind of upset like I had almost used a loophole to entry the country, but stamped me in. She did stress, it was for *one time only*, I'm not sure what is the extent of this check though.